# Project 'XXXXXX' does not have a lock file. Please run "dotnet restore" to generate a new lock file

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr, asp.net-core-webapi

I have `ASP.NET Core Web API` project and `.Net Core Library` project.  The Web API  has reference to Library project as `target : project`. Name of the library project is `Transformations`.
Below is the project.json for both the projects

**project.json for Web API**

```
"dependencies": {
   "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "platform"
  },
   "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
   "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
   "Transformations": {
            "target": "project"
    },
   "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
   "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.3.0-dev-10125",
   "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "3.0.0",
   "Serilog.Settings.Configuration": "2.1.0",
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0"
},
```

**project.json for Library project**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "Production": {},
    "Staging": {}
  }
}
```

On the build server below is the project structure for Api & Transformation projects.

```
 D:\Jenkins\MyJenkinsProject\workspace\src\MySolution
                                                   \Api
                                                   \Transformation
```

On the build server I executed the following commands

```
  D:\Jenkins\MyJenkinsProject\workspace\src\MySolution\Api>dotnet restore
```

and then

```
  D:\Jenkins\MyJenkinsProject\workspace\src\MySolution\Api>dotnet build
```

I get error

> Project Transformations does not have a lock file. Please run
>   "dotnet restore" to generate a new lock file.

Now if I run the following the following commands in the order, then everything works fine.

```
  D:\Jenkins\MyJenkinsProject\workspace\src\MySolution\Transformation>dotnet restore
  D:\Jenkins\MyJenkinsProject\workspace\src\MySolution\Api>dotnet restore
  D:\Jenkins\MyJenkinsProject\workspace\src\MySolution\Api>dotnet build
```

**Questions**
1>When library is referenced as project in API project why do I need to run `dotnet restore` separately for library project? Why cant it `restores` referened project implicitly?

Comment: @hobbs I'm looking for why its not implicitly restoring the referenced projects. am I missing anything? If I  have several library projects referenced from main API project and then I have to execute `dotnet restore` for every library project first. I was hoping I should be able to just restore main project ( ie API in this case). Also I'm doing this on build server. So now when I add the new library project then I also have to update my build scripts to restore the new project.

Answer (score 3):

[From Zlatko Knezevic](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4065#issuecomment-241037969):

> This behavior is by design. […] If you wish to restore all of the dependencies for all your projects in one go, so to speak, just run `dotnet restore` at the root of your solution (where you have the `global.json` file).

Answer (score -2):

i believe you can just do a `dotnet build` directly. it should automatically do a `dotnet restore`.